# Run JAX-WS on Tomcat with Axis2

Tags: tomcat, jax-ws, apache-axis

I have some trouble to deploy a JAX-WS web service on tomcat. It seems that tomcat does not use axis automatically to run soap web services... And so I get an error because my web service class can not be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet.

How can I configure tomcat, in order to run automatically JAX-WS web services with axis2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out how to run automatically JAX-WS web services with axis2 on Tomcat server. 
The web service must be export into a .jar file and copy to the {axis2_home}\WEB-INF\services folder. In this way the web service will be launch automatically.

NB: the .jar file must contain the source file and the the services.xml file in the META-INF directory.